# WordPress theme is eliminating my PayPal purchase link's ampersand and all text afterwards

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, paypal, ampersand

I've encountered a strange error in a theme called "Faith" (by Chimpstudio). When user publishes or updates the page, the PayPal link doesn't write to the database properly.

As far as I'm aware, the value being written to the database is contained in an XML array, like so:

```
noSimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick )
```

The link that should be publishing/updating (before hitting Publish/Update) is:

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick*&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX*

The "*&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX*" is not being saved, which means users cannot purchase my client's product.

Potential solution: I've been digging through the theme's .php files, looking for an opportunity to intercept the value being passed to the WordPress database. The idea was to wrap/encode the variable before it gets send to the WP database, with the hope that the entire URL string remains unchanged at the "*&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX*" part of the URL.

Any solutions or ideas which may help?

EDIT: This may be a relevant piece of code from the admin_functions.php file:

```
function events_meta_save($post_id) {

    global $wpdb;

    if (empty($_POST["event_ticket_price"])){ $_POST["event_ticket_price"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_social_sharing"])){ $_POST["event_social_sharing"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_buy_now"])){ $_POST["event_buy_now"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_phone_no"])){ $_POST["event_phone_no"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["switch_footer_widgets"])){ $_POST["switch_footer_widgets"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_start_time"])){ $_POST["event_start_time"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_end_time"])){ $_POST["event_end_time"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_all_day"])){ $_POST["event_all_day"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_address"])){ $_POST["event_address"] = "";}

     if (empty($_POST["event_ticket_options"])){ $_POST["event_ticket_options"] = "";}

    if (empty($_POST["event_map"])){ $_POST["event_map"] = "";}


    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("<event></event>");


        $sxe->addChild('event_ticket_price', $_POST['event_ticket_price'] );


        $sxe->addChild('event_social_sharing', $_POST["event_social_sharing"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_buy_now', $_POST["event_buy_now"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_phone_no', $_POST["event_phone_no"]);

        $sxe->addChild('switch_footer_widgets', $_POST["switch_footer_widgets"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_start_time', $_POST["event_start_time"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_end_time', $_POST["event_end_time"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_all_day', $_POST["event_all_day"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_ticket_options', $_POST["event_ticket_options"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_address', $_POST["event_address"]);

        $sxe->addChild('event_map', $_POST["event_map"]);

    echo "<pre>BPOST: ".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";
    print_r($sxe);

    $sxe = save_layout_xml($sxe);
    print_r($sxe);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'cs_event_meta', $sxe->asXML());

}
```

Additionally, here's more code for the XML side from the events.php file:

```
// event custom fields start
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cs_event_meta' );  
function cs_event_meta()
{
    add_meta_box( 'event_meta', 'Event Options', 'cs_event_meta_data', 'events', 'normal', 'high' );
}
function cs_event_meta_data($post) {
    $cs_event_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_event_meta", true);
    global $cs_xmlObject;
    if ( $cs_event_meta <> "" ) {
        $cs_xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_event_meta);
            $event_ticket_price = $cs_xmlObject->event_ticket_price;
            $event_social_sharing = $cs_xmlObject->event_social_sharing;
            $event_start_time = $cs_xmlObject->event_start_time;
            $event_end_time = $cs_xmlObject->event_end_time;
            $event_all_day = $cs_xmlObject->event_all_day;
            $event_address = $cs_xmlObject->event_address;
            $event_loc_lat = $cs_xmlObject->event_loc_lat;
            $event_loc_long = $cs_xmlObject->event_loc_long;
            $event_loc_zoom = $cs_xmlObject->event_loc_zoom;

            $testVar = $cs_xmlObject->event_buy_now;

            if (strstr($cs_xmlObject->event_buy_now, "&amp;"))
            {
                echo "yes"; //$event_buy_now = ($cs_xmlObject->event_buy_now . 'FINDME(yes)');
                print_r ($testVar);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "no"; //$event_buy_now = ($cs_xmlObject->event_buy_now . 'FINDME(no)');
                print_r ($testVar);
                print_r ($cs_xmlObject);
            }

            $event_ticket_options = $cs_xmlObject->event_ticket_options;
            $event_map = $cs_xmlObject->event_map;
    }
    else {
        $event_ticket_price = '';
        $slider_id = '';

        $event_social_sharing = '';
        $event_related = '';
        $event_start_time = '';
        $event_end_time = '';
        $event_all_day = '';
        $event_address = '';
        $event_loc_lat = '';
        $event_loc_long = '';
        $event_loc_zoom = '';
        $inside_event_related_post_title = '';
        $event_map = '';
        $event_buy_now = '';
        $event_ticket_options = '';
    }
```

NOTE: Both of these code snippets are located in the parent theme's /include/ directory. At this point, there is no child theme -- and if necessary, a child theme will be created to implement these updates.

Comment: Could you put an `&amp;` in this link, instead of the literal ampersand, to see if that sticks? It is not valid as HTML unless it is rendered as an entity anyway. As it is, the browser will look at that and possibly get `&hosted` from it - though most do a good job of guessing what you meant.

Comment: Hey Halfer, thanks for your reply!

I have manually entered &amp; in the place of the ampersand on the front-end, and the back-end will save the data properly. 

The stumbling block with this approach is that we don't want our clients have to put &amp; every time they add a paypal link to their event. So, I guess the only remaining solution would be to find out where the form is nabbing the link from and replacing the & with &amp; while returning it as a string for the WordPress DB to store.

Comment: Is it the theme that saves the link, or a plugin? My view is that it's not the theme's job to do this sort of stuff, but it'd not surprise me if it does anyway. Dig into the theme files and see what is in there. Maybe you can set up a child theme that intercepts the relevant call? (on the basis that editing themes themselves is not a good idea, as it prevents upgrading).

Comment: Sadly, I think it might be the theme doing the saving.

EDIT: If not, I believe woo commerce is responsible for saving the form, although I've only found evidence of forms being processed within the parent theme (there is no child theme setup).

Comment: Alright, well a child theme might well fix it up relatively cleanly anyway. Have a dig - and if you find relevant code, please update your question with what you find. If there is no child theme, make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use jQuery and .change() to detect new content in an input. When the field gets changed, have it change the & to & amp; Might be a dirty hack, but if this is standing between you and payday, have at 'er.

Comment: +1. It's a hack alright, but so long as the OP tries to fix on the server side later on, this is a good call.

Comment: A hack indeed, but it worked without having to create a child theme. Thanks PlugTrade.com + Halfer!